# Looking for a projection used for Nova Scotia in 1924

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, canada

I have a map of Nova Scotia published by the Department of the Interior Canada in 1924 which I would like to georeference.

The map has a graticule labeled with latitude and longitude. According to a note on the map, the prime meridian is Greenwich. It's not a Conformal projections since lat/long do not meet perpendicular.

I have read that the Department of the Interior Canada was using a Polyconic projection before replaced with the 1932 Lambert
Conformal Conics. (https://www.asprs.org/a/resources/grids/12-97-canada.pdf)

Were there other projections used in 1924? What projection and datum is most likely used for a map of Nova Scotia in 1924?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polyconic seems to me with good chances.

In this document: https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1453/report.pdf, page 106, more details about the polyconic projection.

> **Usage**:
>   The sole projection used for large-scale
>   mapping in the ellipsoidal form (topographic
>   quadrangles) of the United States by the U.S.
>   Geological Survey until the 1950's
>   Basis for Progressive Military Grid used by
>   the U.S. Army until the 1940's
>   Projection for many early coastal charts by
>   the U.S. Coast and Geodetic Survey
>   **Origin**:
>   Apparently originated about 1820 by Ferdinand
>   Rudolph Hassler (1770-1843), first director of
>   the Survey of the Coast (later the U.S. Coast
>   and Geodetic Survey)

Here a map of Nova Scotia, 1924, found at: http://rumseysid.lunaimaging.com/mrsid/mrsid_images/Rumsey/SIDS/D5005/5028155.sid?image=/D5005/5028155.sid (286MB), seems to have the central meridian at -64 degrees (approx.).

[image: map1]

Here a OSM map with a 1 degree grid, reprojected to `+proj=poly +lon_0=-64 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`:

[image: map2]